# Retrieve individual values from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm in need of retrieving individual data from a php array. This is how my array looks like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [membername] => Moni
        [memberid] => 5
        [membertype] => 1
        [roleid] => 1
    )
)
```

I got this by writong this `print_r($result);`

This is how I tried to retrieve individual data:

```
$login = TableRegistry::get('login');
$result = $login->loginuser($loginid, $password);

print_r($result);
echo $result->memberid;
```

But, I get this error:  `Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller\LoginController.php, line 17]`

This is line-17: `echo $result->memberid;`

So, how can I do this? How can I retrieve individual data?

Comment: function `$login->loginuser` return `array` of `stdClass`

Answer (score 3):

just replace `echo $result->memberid;` by `echo $result[0]->memberid;`

Answer (score 3):

With that array, you can get it this way:

```
$login = TableRegistry::get('login');
$result = $login->loginuser($loginid, $password);

if (isset($result[0]) && isset($result[0]->memberid)) {
    echo $result[0]->memberid;
}
```

Hence the extra check that I provided so that the code can run without errors.